# Why does my project not appear in the final render after I render it?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So I’m working on this project, and I’ve tried to render it multiple times, turn down the samples, turned down the lights paths, and just tweaked some settings to make it render faster. And when I go to render it, neither the render view or the final render image shows up. And I could see the render view before I restarted my laptop but now I can’t even see that.

Comment: without seeing any of your settings your question is way to vague. Since you are new here it might be the best if you provide your blend file.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up